# Multiple elements in .Select()

Tags: c#, linq, select

It's probably easy thing but for some reason i'm unable to find solution.

Lets say i have collection of specific type, best example - Person.
And i want to take only FirstName, LastName, and Age, and ignore the rest.

So far i have tried:

```cs
var list2 = list1.Select(x => { x.FirstName; x.LastName; x.Age });
```

```
var list2 = list1.Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Age });
```

But it won't even compile.

Comment: Why do you say that it doesn't compile? The second one seems right to me. Can you please share more of your code?

Comment: I know this may seem silly but have you imported the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: @GlynnHurrell i have it.

Comment: @StepTNT its in fuction which returns collection of Person type. So it says it can't return anonymous type.

Comment: Are you trying to return `list2` in a method that returns an `IEnumerable<Person>`?

Comment: It'll probably help if you post the method containing the code

Comment: and also a clarification of what type list1 is as @stepTNT said above. There is no issue with your second attempt if list1 of type List<T>

Comment: You cannot return an anonymous type or collection of anonymous types from a method. Either use tuples instead of anonymous types, or create a model class with three properties.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov this might be solution. I'm pretty sure there is a thing called view model and it seems to be good strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, seems like you want to strip some properties from your `Person` objects, by selecting just a few of them.

This is one way you can do it:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    // This property will be stripped
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(FirstName)}: {FirstName}, {nameof(LastName)}: {LastName}, {nameof(Age)}: {Age}, {nameof(OtherProperty)}: {OtherProperty}";
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<Person> StrippedPersons(IEnumerable<Person> source)
    {
        // Selects only some of the properties that you want to return
        return source.Select(x => new Person
        {
            FirstName = x.FirstName, 
            LastName = x.LastName, 
            Age = x.Age
        });
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person
            {
                Age = 10,
                FirstName = "First",
                LastName = "Last",
                OtherProperty = "THIS WILL BE DISCARDED"
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", list1));

        var list2 = StrippedPerson(list1).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", list2));
    }
}
```

Output is:

> FirstName: First, LastName: Last, Age: 10, OtherProperty: THIS WILL BE DISCARDED
>
> FirstName: First, LastName: Last, Age: 10, OtherProperty:

If you want this to be somehow dynamic, in the sense that you want to pass the name of the needed properties as a parameter to your method instead of having them hardcoded, we may need to use reflection and it's better to edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example works fine:

```
    cs.Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Age });
```

An even better way is to use a value tuple, they use less memory and are much easier to garbage collect (fewer roots):

```
    cs.Select(x => (x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Age));
```

[Online reference](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6H6Xnv)

Comment: I think that his method must return a collection of `Person`, at least this is what I got from his question + comments.